# Need a query to select a new field that is 5 from the current field

Tags: mysql

[image: 1]

My goal is to create a sql query that populates release field with 5th record below that So 2017-06-04 would be 5 from the date. I can't use any date functions because the dates are not always in order. Here's what I have so far.

```
    select rowNum, date, (select date from workdays where rowNum = ?)
    as release from workdays
```

Comment: There is no internal order for MySQL records.

Comment: If rownum is intact then the solution is trivial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
    select rowNum, date, 
   (select date from workdays b where b.rowNum = a.rowNum + 4 ) as release from workdays a
```

Comment: This was definitely the way. Thank you!